# is there a way in gradle to update an existing jar?

Tags: gradle, jar

The stand-alone jar tool has the "u" option to add files to an existing jar.
Is there a built-in way to use the gradle jar api to do the same thing?

I would like to avoid using a gradle exec task to invoke the jar tool.

Comment: Could you attach images?

Answer (score 0):

gradle does not update existing jars

you can achieve merging in multiple ways depending on you needs

ex: what takes precedence (old files or new files)

```
jar {
    from zipTree('junit-4.12.jar')
}
```

or you can have extra Jar task where you explicitly do the same

```
task mergedJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: jar) {
    archiveClassifier = 'merged'
    from zipTree('junit-4.12.jar')
    from zipTree(jar.archiveFile)
}
```